# Using IDispatchMessageInspector to get request's remote address

Tags: c#, wcf, idispatchmessageinspector

I'm trying to follow this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/19/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx

My aim is to somehow get the remote address of the incoming request, but for some reason the address either is nowhere to be seen in any of the parameters, or is null.

Here's the interface I'm implementing:

```
public interface IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext);
    void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState);
}
```

The method I'm trying to get the remote address in is `AfterReceiveRequest`. I've checked both parameters `request` and `channel`. Also, it seems that `channel.RemoteAddress` is where it should be, but that property is null for some reason. The `request` parameter is also null, but I'm guessing that's because I'm doing a GET and not a POST.

Below is the signature of the method I'm invoking to test this out.

```
[OperationContract, WebGet( UriTemplate = "{*path}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string[] GetList(string path);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.From`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message.headers.aspx)

OR

`(OperationContext.Current. IncomingMessageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty).Address`

OR

`HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` (BEWARE this one requires setting `<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>`)

Answer (score 1):

Use this from `IDispatchMessageInspector` implementation:

```
var remoteEndpoint = request.Properties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
var ipAddress = remoteEndpoint.Address;
```

Answer (score 0):

The information will be in the request headers, found using:

```
WebHeaderCollection headers = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers;
```

Comment: I did try that as well at some point, but the headers didn't have what I was looking for. Yahia's solution seems to work fine.